# Over-writing an edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

A curious thing happened. I edited the tags on a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534377/mathematics-problem-of-natural-numbers?). Simultaneously, a user proposed an edit to the title of the question. That user's edit was approved a few minutes later, and one effect of the approval, not intended by the other user or the approver, was to undo my tag edit. Is that a bug?

Comment: I think it depends on if the other user started to edit before or after you finished your tag edit. If they started before, then their version of the question which they are editing will have the old tags and they'll get carried forward once their edit is accepted. If they started after, then the version they're correcting should have your new tags so the tags won't be reverted. I don't think the editing system is smart enough to 'merge' different kinds of edits.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11231/43351

Comment: @Daniel, thanks (and thanks also to Farin). It appears the other user started before and, as you say, the old tags got carried forward. But it also appears that the other user's suggestion was presented to the reviewer as removing a tag (see the answer posted by Sklivvz). That would indeed be a consequence of approving the edit (though I don't see why that should be), so it's good that the reviewer gets that notice, but it misrepresents the other user's intentions.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8917/editing-long-questions-in-stages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeline:

- 2013-10-21 11:59:14Z Gerry Myerson     edited tags
- 2013-10-21 11:59:17Z suggested     Carsten Schultz

The edit was suggested exactly 3 seconds after your edit. In other words, it was always shown as "changing the title and removing a tag" to the reviewers -- there was no overwrite.

You can see the public timeline here: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/534377/revisions but it does not show the exact times the edit was suggested, which I've found in the mod-only logs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. I think it's safe to assume that it took Carsten more than 3 seconds to propose his edit, so he would have been unaware that I had added a tag, and "removing a tag" would not have been his intention. It seems the software is interpreting Carsten's actions --- contrary to Carsten's intentions --- as "removing a tag". Misrepresenting an editor's actions strikes me as a bug, but I guess my grievance is with the reviewer who accepted the edit without putting the tag back in.